# Targeting event.target instance name and not object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a drag and drop SWF I created and am now trying to implement a new function where I need to pass the instance and x/y coordinates to a different function outside of the startDrag and stopDrag functions.  I'm trying to target the instance name by setting up a variable and storing the event.target in in the startDrag function.

However, the issue is that when I run a trace on that variable, it doesn't return the instance name.  For example, I have a movieclip with an instance name of myClip1.  Yet, when I run a trace on the variable, the console reports it as [object myClip1_1].

How can I instead pass the actual instance to the variable so I can use with the external function?

**Update:** I figured out why I was getting "object myClip1_1" as the output: somehow AS Linkage in the library got turned on. I've disabled that, but now, when I run a trace on event.target and event.currentTarget, I just get "[output MovieClip]" and not the instance name. What gives?

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you are doing this: trace(myVariable), where you should be doing this: trace(myVariable.name).

Comment: For future reference, always include the code you are having trouble with. Makes it far easier to help you.

Comment: Why do you need to target the instance name?

Comment: Like I asked below and like Pan asked above, why do you need the instance name?  The instance given back from event.target IS the instance that was dragged.  If you are now receiving the correct target you should be able to set the variable as I described in my answer. currentDragObject = event.target.  Then use currentDragObject elsewhere in the code for whatever you need.

Comment: The problem is that if I pass the variable to my external function, I get an error: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert myClip1_1@7ffff0122e1 to com.adobe.sync.events.SyncSwfEvent.at CustomPod_fla::MainTimeline/pickUp().  However, if I plug in an instance name of a movieclip I've planted on the stage (as a test), the external function works correctly.  The variable of myMC (or currentDragObject in your example) is not passing the instance of the movieclip on the actual stage.

Answer (score 1):

just add .name to event.target:

```
event.target.name
```

EDIT:

You shouldn't need the instance name to connect to the object that is being dragged. just say in the **startDrag** function:

```
currentDragObject = event.target.
```

**currentDragObject** is defined at the global scope:

```
var currentDragObject:MovieClip;
```

In this manner, **currentDragObject** will always be reset to the object being dragged.

Comment: This gives me the instance name, but then I need to pass back the actual instance to my other function.  How would I convert that string back to the actual instance?

Comment: event.target should do that.  If you are getting numbers added to your instance then you might not have all instances of it named on the timeline.  If event.target doesn't work, try using event.currentTarget.  Both of those should return the instance of the object that was clicked on.

Comment: Both don't.  I've tried tracing both event.target and event.currentTarget and they both return [object myClip1_1] and not the actual instance name of "myClip1".

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you need to trace it?  See my edit please.

Comment: I'm only tracing to see what event.target and event.currentTarget are referencing.  I would normally expect event.currentTarget to give me the actual instance, but it doesn't.  I also did previously what you recommended.  I have a variable called "myMC" which is supposed to be equal to the event.currentTarget, but again, myMC gives me the same output as event.target and event.currentTarget, which is "[object myClip1_1]" and not the instance.